# PHP Goto work around needed please

Tags: php, wordpress

Total noob to PHP and I am trying to put this in the header of my wordpress file:

```
<?php 
$meta = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$country = $meta['geoplugin_countryCode'];
if (($country=='GB') or ($country=='US')) {
exit;
} else {
header("Location: http://google.com");
exit;
}
?>
```

Where the page code would get executed if from GB or US else get kicked to google.

Can't get it to work so guidance required please.

Cheerz

Ukphoneguy

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Not sure I'd rely too much on this service. My attempt to query it put me 200 miles from my actual location.

Comment: @ Mike W Thanks for the input but not using it for city location just to stop china Russia etc.... trying to hack my site. I have the log in page locked out but it was getting a war of attrition blocking ip's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
if (($country != 'GB') and ($country != 'US')) header("Location: http://google.com");
```

Comment: someone flagged this, I recommend explaining.

Comment: @ Dusan Plavak - THANK YOU did exactly what I wanted. The way I understand this - if country not equal and country not equal kick them to google. Brilliant

Comment: Yes, but the better solution is what @Jonathon Reinhart provided. Because imagine that you will have like 50 countries which are not allowed ,  then you will need to add other 50 AND expressions. So again BETTER solution is Jonathon Reinharts, it also better code style practice...

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to `exit;` in the "allowed" case.

```
$allowed = array('GB', 'US');
if (!in_array($country, $allowed)) {
    // Not an allowed country. Redirect.
    header("Location: http://google.com");
    exit;
}

// The rest of your code for valid countries goes here
```

Your problems is that you were calling `exit`, even for GB and US. You only call `exit` when you want to completely stop executing any more PHP code (which is not what you wanted).

Comment: @ Jonathon Thanks for your input however I decided to use Dusan's solution. Steep learning curve for me but bitten by the bug now LOL

Comment: @UKPhoneguy Ok, just read the documentation for those functions - it's nothing complicated.